# Auto Refresh Page on Model Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, signalr

My SignalR Hub pushes data every 5 minutes to all Clients.

The clients establish a connection via C# part in the Controller.
I want the client to update itself, after receiving data.

Are there any possibillitys to do this with c# only or do i need inevitably ajay?
I know the Idea of auto reload the page every xseconds, but i dont like that many wasteful reloads.

Comment: You could do it with knockout or angular, have you test ?

Answer (score 0):

If the client is connected through a websocket connection via the browser it is better to dynamically alter the webpage elements based upon the information you receive via sockets.

For example if we want an updated status of everyone in a socket room, we send a list of users in JSON format to every client. The client than processes this information using javascript and applies visual feedback to the HTML DOM.

Good luck!